# IF ELSE condition in SQL select

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I want to do a if-else condition statement in SQL Server but am not sure how.

Inside the stored procedure I have the following parameters:

```
@MarketId nvarchar (10),
@RegionId nvarchar (10)
```

And the following statement:

```
select * from Interaction I
where 
(@MarketId = 0 ) OR (I.MarketId = (SELECT Id FROM Market WHERE ExternalId = @MarketId))
```

What I want to do is to check the value of `@MarketId`

```
if @MarketId = 0
```

then I want the where condition for `I.MarketId` to get its Ids from elsewhere like

```
(SELECT ID FROM Market WHERE ExternalId = @RegionId)
```

otherwise, if its 1, then I just want to leave it as is and get the Id from `@MarketId` instead of `@RegionId`..

How should I go about this?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand well. So, if `@MarketId = 0` then you want to retrieve from the other condidition, that is clear enough. But, if `@MarketId = 1`, then you want the `Id` from `@MarketId`, so you want `1`?

Comment: Sry, it could also be other values like 2,3,400.  I just used 1 as example

Comment: So the condition is: IF @MarketID = 0 Begin - End ...ELSE everything else?

Answer (score 4):

This should work:

```
SELECT *
FROM Interaction I
WHERE ( @MarketID = 0 
        AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Market 
                    WHERE ExternalId = @RegionId AND Id = I.MarketID)
OR I.MarketID = @MarketID
```